# Add WooCommerce Add to Cart buttons conditionally on custom post types

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I want to display the WooCommerce Add to Cart button conditionally on a custom post type page. Here is my situation.

**Parent theme** = removes the button by default with the following `remove_action` hook

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

**Child theme** = I bring it back re-adding the action

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 8);
```

And it works. But in my child theme, I have an option to call this conditionally. So the complete code to bring back the buttons on my child theme are like this

```
if (get_option('my_wc_opt') == 1) {
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 8);
}
```

Now users can either call this or not with an option field.

**Problem** = Regardless of whether users call the function (*bringing back add to cart buttons*) with the option `my_wc_opt`, I want to always make it display on a custom post type page, say `my_custom_post_type`

I tried with this

```
if(is_singular('my_custom_post_type')){
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 8);
}
```

But it does not work.

How I can always display the buttons on that custom post type irrespective of whether choose the option or not for the shop page.

Comment: **`woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`** hook is used exclusively on woocommerce shop archives pages (**loop**), so it can't work on single pages, posts, custom posts…